# Regular expression PHP get content between words

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

been racking my brain with trying to learn how regular expressions work in php.

Im trying to get the information after the semi colons but before the next **keyword:** starts

Here is my text which i have managed to use regular expressions to strip the html out first.

> Title:2012 BMW M5 Concept Location:Munich - Germany
>   Reference:091Comments:For 25 years now, the fascinating combination of
>   supreme driving comfort experienced in a premium upper
>   midrangeFrom:Jim Smith jim@jimsemail.com.au  0987541231

The text above is really just an example but exactly in the same format as my text.

what i need is this:

1. Title=2012 BMW M5 Concept
2. Location=Munich Germany
3. Reference=091
4. Comments=For 25 years now, the fascinating combination of supreme driving comfort experienced in a premium upper midrange
5. From=Jim Smith jim@jimsemail.com.au 0987541231

With the last result **5. From:** i can always write a bit extra to extract the email, however if someone could help with the extraction of the name and also the phone number which may not always be exactly that many digits i would be very gratefully grateful :)

so far i have this to successfully get the refernce number:

```
if (preg_match("/Reference:[0-9]{3}/", $decodedmessage, $matches_id)) 
{ 
echo "Reference=".preg_replace("/Reference:/","",$matches_id[0]); 
}
```

Thanks in advance
Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can use:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+):([^:]+)(?=\s)/', '{{your data}}', $arr);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title:2012 BMW M5 Concept
            [1] => Location:Munich - Germany
            [2] => 091Comments:For 25 years now, the fascinating combination of supreme driving comfort experienced in a premium upper
            [3] => midrangeFrom:Jim Smith jim@jimsemail.com.au
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => Location
            [2] => 091Comments
            [3] => midrangeFrom
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012 BMW M5 Concept
            [1] => Munich - Germany
            [2] => For 25 years now, the fascinating combination of supreme driving comfort experienced in a premium upper
            [3] => Jim Smith jim@jimsemail.com.au
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi Jacob - thanks for that. How do i output that array? do i need echo $arr[0] ? i know it sounds like a dumb question but its totally new to me.

Comment: I got it print_r($arr); 

But how did you get it to print down the page? mine is in one big long line and i  just want it a bit clearer before i start the next bit of processing

Comment: @jonny take a look at the page source. (right click>view source) or wrap it in a `<pre> tag</pre>`